# Duplicated DLL in the "Detected Dependencies" folder

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, dependencies

In my solution I have to project using the same references (AxInterop.QTOControlLib.dll, Interop.QTOControlLib.dll and Interop.QTOLibrary.dll).

My problem is that in my deployement project, these dependencies appear twice in the "Detected Dependencies" folder, thus lead to several warning like :
*Warning    1   Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\interop.qtocontrollib.dll') C:\xxx\xxx\xxxx.vdproj*

How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread in this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/9de261e2-8c76-4235-a8c0-95acb7f7ec36/) on MSDN discusses a similar problem and offers a few suggestions.